# Append Wordpress permalink URL

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to modify a plugin which sends out url's in an email notification.

The code in the plugin is this

```
<?php the_title(); ?>: <?php the_job_permalink(); ?>
```

It displays the following in the email

Front End Risk Account Manager: http://tbc-recruit.com/job/front-end-risk-account-manager/

What I'd like to end up with is a url in this format

http://tbc-recruit.com/job/front-end-risk-account-manager/?utm_source=jobalerts&utm_medium=email

I have tried the following

```
<?php 
$alerturl = the_job_permalink();
$alerturl .= "?utm_source=jobalerts&utm_medium=email";
?>

<?php the_title(); ?>:<?php echo $alerturl; ?>
```

That code gives the following output

Front End Risk Account Manager:?utm_source=jobalerts&utm_medium=email

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe because `the_job_permalink()` show html content like

```
<a href="http://tbc-recruit.com/job/front-end-risk-account-manager/">http://tbc-recruit.com/job/front-end-risk-account-manager/</a>
```

You should use `get_permalink()`

```
<?php
$alerturl = get_permalink() . '?utm_source=jobalerts&utm_medium=email'; 
?>
<?php the_title(); ?>:<?php echo '<a href="' . $alerturl . '"> ' . $alerturl . '</a>'; ?>
```

I hope this helped you

Answer (score 0):

Use `get_the_title()` instead of `the_title()`